# what databases can be used with java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am doing an undergrad final project, and need to justify my choice of MySQL for the database element of my project.  Truth is, it's the only one I can really use, and hence I went for it.

What other database systems could I have used? Any advantages and disadvantages of these over MySQL?

Comment: As always, the answer depends on your needs.  Could you explain the role that the relational database plays in your project?  Also, can you clarify what is meant by "it's the only one I can really use"?

Comment: i am trying to implement access controls using a category based model in a banking environment.  The database will hold data about "customers" and their transactions, accounts etc.  It also will hold details about employees.  this data will then be used to categorise each user of the system, and in turn will decide whether actions performed by the users will be permitted or denied.  

"only one i can really use" meaning its the only thing i have learnt about at university, but in theory only - not in practice. 

hope that helps...?!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In fact, you can use every database which is accessible through a [JDBC driver](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers). Almost all self-respected RDBMS vendors provides a fullworthy JDBC driver for download at their homepage. Just Google "[vendorname] jdbc driver download" to find it. Here's an overview:

- [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
- [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) (note: older versions doesn't support generated keys).
- [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) (note: older versions doesn't support generated keys).
- [MSSQL JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99B21B65-E98F-4A61-B811-19912601FDC9&displaylang=en) (or performancewise better, the [jTDS JDBC driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/))
- DB2 JDBC driver is hard to find in IBM's online forest, but it's usually already included in the `/java` folder of the DB2 installation.

This way you can use the [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) transparently to access either of the databases.

As to which database to choose, just look at the features, robustness, performance, etc the RDBMS provides and the budget you have -if it isn't freeware. I myself tend to prefer PostgreSQL.

Instead of a fullfledged database server, you can also consider an *embedded* Javabased database, such as [<strike>Sun</strike> Oracle JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), each which are of course accessible through the JDBC API the usual way.

Comment: One more embedded solution to add to the list: SQLite, available in both pure-Java and JNI-based versions.

Comment: @BalusC Which of these don't need installation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any relational database that has a JDBC driver.  These would include PostgreSQL, Hypersonic SQL, MySQL, SQLLite on the free side and Oracle, MS SQL Server, and others on the paid side.

The biggest advantage accrued to MySQL in your case is that it's free and you know it. That's enough to make it suitable for what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You could have used pretty much **ANY** database. MSSQL, SQLite, Postgre, Oracle or [put your choice here]

There's a driver for pretty much any database to integrate with Java. [This](http://devapp.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers#skip2content) is a great place to find out all the DB's java support, as well as how to integrate

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [list of vendors who have endorsed the JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/reference/industrysupport/index.html) maintained by Sun. Also see the list of third-party [JDBC technology-enabled drivers](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers) which are currently shipping.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned MySQL and database. For the case you are free to usa a non RDBMS you can check [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/).

Advantage: pure OO/Java persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Many have said this already, but pretty much any database will work. Consider including [the top 5](https://ashintech.medium.com/5-best-databases-to-use-with-java-a9d3d601daec) (based on rankings, popularity) in your writeup.